# Reference request for Delaunay's proof of isoperimetric property

Tags: differential-geometry

I found the following claim on [this](https://www.mathcurve.com/courbes3d.gb/cercle_geodesique/cercle_geodesique.shtml) website:

> Delaunay proved that, just as in the plane, the closed curves with
>   minimal length enclosing a given area, or with given length enclosing
>   the larger area, are the geodesic circles in the second sense
>   (isoperimetric property)

Here "geodesic circles in the second sense" means closed curves with constant geodesic curvature. The reference quoted is

> Delaunay in 1843 ( J. M.,1843, vol. 8, pages 231-244)

But I am unable to find anything with just these bits of information. Can anyone decipher it or is there any other reference for this claim?